# How do I set up Strawberry Perl in MSYS?

Tags: perl, msys, strawberry-perl

I have [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) and have msys Perl 5.6 removed.

Now `perl` will invoke Strawberry (due to `PATH` env) but how do I map the `perl` command in `.pl` or other Perl script files which have `#!/bin/perl` or `#!/usr/bin/perl` shebang lines?

I was thinking of making a hardlink to *perl.exe* in *msys/bin* or merge the whole Strawberry inside the *msys* directory, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please note that Strawberry Perl and MSYS Perl (/usr/bin/perl) probably isn't 100% compatible, especially when it comes to unixy stuff that the MSYS supports and Strawberry, which is native Windows, doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to **create a symlink to the Strawberry Perl executable from within MSYS** <sup>Tip of the hat to [smaudet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420917/smaudet) for his input</sup>:

First, remove or rename the Perl executables that the MSYS installation came with, if any (which the OP has already done); e.g.:

```
mv /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl.msys 
mv /usr/bin/cpan /usr/bin/cpan.msys
```

Then create a symlink to Strawberry Perl's executable in its place:

```
ln -s /c/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe /usr/bin/perl

# Unfortunately, doing the same for `cpan` doesn't work directly, because
# Strawberry Perl's `cpan` executable is a *batch* file, `cpan.bat`, which
# cannot be directly invoked from MSYS.
# To invoke it from MSYS (assuming it is in the %PATH%):
#   cmd /c 'cpan.bat ...'
# With an explicit path:
#   cmd /c 'c:\strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat ...'
#
# Here's how to create a stub script that still allows invocation as 
# `cpan`:
echo 'cmd /c "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat $*"'>/usr/bin/cpan && chmod +x /usr/bin/cpan
```

Once the `/usr/bin/perl` symlink is in place, existing scripts with shebang lines `#!/usr/bin/perl` and `#!/bin/perl` will work again (the latter also works, because `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are effectively the same location in MSYS).

Note that scripts written with the more flexible shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env perl` do *not* need this, because `env` will *directly* find Strawberry Perl's `perl.exe` in the path.

---

Some **background**:

Unix-emulation environments such as MSYS and Cygwin do *not* respect Windows' `%PATHEXT%` variable to determine what executable to invoke a (non-binary) file with. In other words: *filename extensions have no meaning with respect to execution* there.

Instead, they *solely go by whether the file has a shebang line*:

- If there is one, the executable specified in the shebang line is used.
- If there is none, the default (POSIX-like) shell `/bin/sh` is used.

  - Thus, trying to invoke `*.bat` or `*.cmd` files directly *fails*, because they don't have a Unix shebang line and are therefore executed by `/bin/sh` rather than `cmd.exe`.

Unlike in Windows, this also works with (executable) files that have no filename extension at all.

Answer (score 0):

this works beautifully on the windows side of the computer, on the MSYS side you may need to

- check the PATH environment variable and fix to include the strawberry perl access path
- check the scripts for complete path in the shebang line (#!/usr/bin/perl).
  Those paths that are absolute in msys are in fact relative to the msys install directory in windows. 
  you may need to "plug" your strawberry perl install to match or change the #! line

in the latter case my recommendation would be to use something like: `#!env perl` that checks the environment for the perl interpreter and alleviate the burden of dealing with /cygdrive/c/my/windows/path/not/visible/from/msys/otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The correct shebang would be, eg. `#!"C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe"`. However, you might prefer to run scripts explicitly with Perl rather than rely on the shebang, eg. `perl script.pl` or `perl "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\cpan"`

Note that Strawberry Perl doesn't get the shebang right for its own scripts, such as `cpan` and `perldoc` . Bug reported at https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=82837